# Acer Aspire 5742G - Computer does not wake up from standby

Tags: windows-7, laptop, acer-aspire, standby

Issue is in Windows 7 as well as in Debian Wheezy.

In Windows every manufacturer recommended Driver is installed and the Bios is on the latest version. Windows was installed from the W7x64 SP1-U Image from Microsoft, not from a Acer recovery Image. The drivers are from Acer's site, too and are the same ones that were in the recovery image.

OSes can launch standby just fine, laptop goes silent, lights off.
When I press any button it either:

- lives up shortly to power off again before the screen turns on.
- blinks the power led, runs the drives, turns them off again, 1 sec passes, the same thing again over and over, like some stuck initialization.

How can I fix that?

PS: I want a working resume from standby, not hardresetting it to get it up again, that would defy the reason for standby.

Comment: Just reading about broken DSDT tables and what to do with them. Brb.

Comment: more wtf than before

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with an Aspire R7 that would sometimes not wake from sleep or standby.  I found somewhere that when the laptop is not responding correctly, do a hard reset.  There is not a way to remove the battery, but there is a tiny pinhole in the back or under side. Has a battery like icon. Press is for about 5 seconds and let go. Turn on your laptop.  If everything looks normal, cool. If not, please take notes on what you see and error codes for more troubleshooting.

Comment: Not what I search for, I can hardreset just fine. But I want to have it wake from standby, not hardreset. I want to use one of the best features of a laptop: Close Lid, Powersaving, Powercord out, laptop in the bag, driving somewhere, powercord in, open laptop, everything open as left with almost no delay.